# Python how to share variable between class methods, and what is the difference between instance attributes and class attributes

Tags: python, oop, self, class-attributes

For example:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self,Attr1):
        self.Attr1 = Attr1

    def method1(self):
        self.var1 = [some codes involves Attr1]

    def method2(self):
        self.var2 = [some codes involves var1 from method1]
```

Is it workable? But the variables in functions are local to the function. I don't know if I can call `var1` from `method1`.

The other way I can think of is to have `self.var1` to be set in `__init__` so it's a class attribute so that I can call it in `method2`. But then I don't want to have a very large `__init__`.

I also read something about a class attributes and an instance attributes — what's the difference between the two?

Comment: the way you've written it at the moment, self.var1 is local to the class, not to method1. It would be callable from method2 as well. You would however need to call method1 first in order to initialise it. It would be better to do this directly under init

Comment: "Is it workable?" - have you tried? Please provide complete working code (i.e. replacing "some code" with a real (possibly toy or sample) code

Comment: `self` refers to the instance. If the object is instantiated you can absolutely us an instance attribute you set in `method1` elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

***Instance Attributes***

The variables that start with `self.` at the class belong to a specific singular class instance (not to a specific method), so it is very workable.

You can initialize them in class constructor:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attribute = 'instance attribute'
```

And you can change their value for each instance separately:

```
a1 = A()
a2 = A()

a2.instance_attribute = 'sabich'

# 'instance attribute' (unchanged)
print(a1.instance_attribute)

# 'sabich'
print(a2.instance_attribute)
```

***Class Attributes***

```
class A:
    a = "class attribute"
```

Class attributes are common to all class instances and owned by the class.

They can be accessed via class name:

```
# 'class attribute'
print(A.a)
```

Or by specific instance:

```
a1 = A()

# 'class attribute'
print(a1.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `self.` already, so the scope of your var1 is the class not the method.

Hence, you can use var1 in any other class method if you refer to it as `self.var1` and if `method1` is called first.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it workable?

Yup.

```
But the variables in functions are local to the function.
```

Nope, they are instance attributes, that is, they are attributes of certain instances of the class.

> I don't know if I can call `var1` from `method1`

You can, but you will need to create an instance and then call the method for that instance.

> The other way I can think of is to have `self.var1` to be set in
> `__init__` so it's a class attribute so that I can call it in
> `method2`

It's better to set it in the constructor, because then you will not have to worry about `method1` being called or not. But you can use it in `method2` without a problem.

> But then I don't want to have a very large `__init__`

You can create helper methods and call them.

```
I also read something about a class attributes and an instance attributes — what's the difference between the two?
```

Class attributes are attributes of classes, that is, they are attributes of the whole set of instances. Instance attributes are instances of attributes. Think about stackoverflow.com users. Each user has a username, that's instance-level. However, the number of users is an attribute of the users as a whole set.